# BASH login in Jenkins

Tags: bash, authentication, jenkins, cygwin

I have Jenkins running as service. I use cygwin to run my unix shell scripts.

on windows (outside Jenkins), I can run the below:
start a dos/windows cmd, 
bash --login -i
. ./myscript.sh

with jenkins however, the build step:
Execute Windows batch command:
c:\cygwin64\bin\bash --login path\to\myscript.sh

I get the below error:

Your group is currently "mkpasswd".  This indicates that your
gid is not in /etc/group and your uid is not in /etc/passwd

I have set my username/password by running
mkpasswd -l [-d] > /etc/passwd
mkgroup  -l [-d] > /etc/group.

it appears that the command bash --login within jenkins does not read from the /etc/asswd and /etc/group files.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

After the user's credential set in cygwin, I create a build step in jenkins with "Execute Windows Batch command":

bash --login -i path\to\myscript.sh

this works for me.